# How to Make Scaled and Transformed Images Scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I've been trying to implement a zoomable image-map.  I'm using scale and transform to take advantage of CSS transitions. It's been working nicely so far. However, I found a problem when using `translate`. The image gets cut off and there's no scrolling available anymore.

The idea in general is when the user clicks on one point, it scales either to fit the screen height or the original size. Also, it translates to maintain the position clicked, to be centered on the screen.

Is there any way to make the translated image scrollable as well, so that the user can zoom in and then scroll over the big image and zoom out and not get the image cut off?

Here is what I've made so far. I recommend playing and hit fullscreen for a better experience:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var zoommed = true;
img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let contentHeight = 600;
  let scale = !zoommed ? 1 : contentHeight / img.offsetHeight;

  img.style.transform = `scale(${scale}) translate(${-e.offsetX*scale + 200}px, ${-e.offsetY*scale + 300}px)`;
  img.parentElement.style.width = `${img.offsetWidth*scale}px`;
  img.parentElement.style.height = `${img.offsetHeight*scale}px`;
  zoommed = !zoommed;
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#screen {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#img {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="img" src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/src/scroll/www/assets/map.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```